# URL Source Image Does Not Display In .Net Core

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core

I've encountered a problem with loading URL images in WPF .Net Core 3.0. I think it is a problem related to the .Net version rather than a code-related issue or anything (given that I don't have the issue in .Net Framework 4.7.2).

This is the problematic line:
`<Image Source="http://cdn-www.airliners.net/aviation-photos/photos/7/0/1/1892107.jpg"/>`

I need to have the image in the URL format, I am pulling it in from an SQL database. By setting the source directly to URL in the example, I believe I've eliminated any possible server-related issues (the original app is a little bit more complicated, but not even this simplified one-liner works).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem is due to the URL having a series of redirects that includes going from `HTTPS` to `HTTP`, which is not secure.

You can see the redirects that are performed by loading the original URL in a browser and checking the network request tab in the developer console:

[image: so many redirects]

You can confirm that this is causing an error by adding a handler to the `Image` control's [`ImageFailed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image.imagefailed?view=netcore-3.0) event:

**Image control:**

```
<Image Source="http://cdn-www.airliners.net/aviation-photos/photos/7/0/1/1892107.jpg" 
        ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed" />
```

**Event handler:**

```
private void Image_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.ErrorException.Message);
}
```

This will result in the following error message being printed to the debug output:

> The remote server returned an error: (301) Moved Permanently.

### Why does this only happen in .NET Core?

`Image` uses `HttpWebRequest` underneath to resolve URL sources. With .NET Core, the `HttpWebRequest` behavior was intentionally changed to not allow following `HTTPS -> HTTP` redirects because it is a security risk. You can check out [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23422) for details, especially [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23422#issuecomment-324079144) from David Shulman:

> Yes, this is by-design in .NET Core. This is a security-related change to prevent HTTPS -> HTTP redirection which is inherently insecure.